# SQL - trigger insert only when a user made an update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table, `customers_accounts`, that tracks some basic information about a customer on an account. When the customer's file is opened, I synchronize the information from an external system so our user gets the most updated information.

```
UPDATE 
    customers_accounts
SET
    first_name = 'bob',
    last_name = 'burger'
WHERE 
    account_number = '12345'
```

When a user updates the account, I do the same query, but I update a column indicating the last user to make the change

```
UPDATE 
    customers_accounts
SET
    first_name = 'bob',
    last_name = 'burger',
    updated_by = 'H Jon Benjamin',
    updated_on = GETDATE()
WHERE 
    account_number = '12345'
```

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve. I want to track changes in a history table, but only log changes when they're made by a user, not if they're from the external system. So my plan was to create a trigger that inserts a row if the user column is not blank on the insert (since the `updated_by` is implicitly null above in the first update)

What I tried is this:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Accounts_Customers_LogUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[Accounts_Customers]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @Now AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @User AS NVARCHAR(150)

    SELECT @User = (SELECT [updated_by] FROM INSERTED)

    IF (@User IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts_Customers-History]
            SELECT *, @User, @Now
            FROM inserted
    END
```

`Accounts_Customers-History` is an exact copy of the table with two additional columns, `change_made_by` and `change_made_on`

It doesn't behave how i'd expect though. It inserts whatever value is in `updated_by` into `change_made_by`, regardless of the value of `updated_by` in the query. So I'm getting logged activity triggered by both the user and the import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`UPDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt was made on a specified column of a table or view. UPDATE() is used anywhere inside the body of a Transact-SQL INSERT or UPDATE trigger to test whether the trigger should execute certain actions.

This means that the `update` function will return `false` for the first update statement in the question, and `true` for the second update statement - which is exactly what you need.

Also, please note you should always specify the columns list in an insert statement, 
and also always specify the columns list in a select statement. ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365890/column-name-or-number-not-match-table-definition-in-table-created-by-create/50370684#50370684))

A revised version of your trigger might look something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Accounts_Customers_LogUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[Accounts_Customers]
AFTER UPDATE

AS

DECLARE @Now as DateTime = GetDate()
IF UPDATE(updated_by)
BEGIN

    -- Always specify the columns list in an insert statement!
    insert into [dbo].[Accounts_Customers-History] (<Columns list>)
    -- Always specify the columns list in a select statement!
    select <columns list>,  @Now
    from inserted

END
```

Please note that the `UPDATE()` function does not give you any indication if the insert or update statement that fired the trigger was successful, nor does it give you an indication if the value of the column has actually changed - it only indicates whether that column was a part of the insert or update statement that fired the trigger - as you can read in the last paragraph of the remarks section:

> If a trigger applies to a column, the UPDATED value will return as true or 1, even if the column value remains unchanged. This is by-design, and the trigger should implement business logic that determines if the insert/update/delete operation is permissible or not.